# Structure of "All that is needed to do something is something"

Tags: sentence-structure

> All that is needed to participate is access to an Internet
>   connection

I don't know why I am confused when I see this structure. I see the part *" all that is needed to do something"* is subject but seeing two linking verbs like *is* in the same sentence makes me feel that it sounds unnatural. Is there any alternative ways to rephrase the sentence ?

I would expect to be written the sentence as follows:

> All that (which is) needed to participate is access to an Internet
>   connection.

Because it is grammatically correct  to say :

> All that he wants is another toy.
>
> All you need to participate is access to an  Internet connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing incorrect with having multiple "is"'s in a sentence.

Maybe what is confusing you is the common phrase

> all that is + is *something*

which means "it is only *something*"

> *All that is* is a round ball.
>   *it is only a round ball*
>
> *All that is* needed to participate is access to an Internet connection
>   *it is only needed to have internet access*

Your other two sentences are correct.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to ask do you think if  "all that is" fixed structure which always means " it is only" or  it has a structure like  " all  + relative clause with pronoun that" .  If the latter is the case , can we rewrite the sentence as     " All needed to participate is access to an Internet connection."

Comment: "All needed to participate is access to an Internet connection" sounds misspoken and might be understood to mean "All needed an internet connection to participate" since you are making "all" the subject instead of "all that is needed" as the subject. It changes the meaning of your sentence. "You only need internet connection", "Only an internet connection is necessary", "All you need is an internet connection" has the same meaning as your original sentence.